# Angular and ASP .NET 5 Web API - Not receiving Bearer Token in API when making requests with Angular

Tags: .net, angular, authentication, jwt, authorization

So, for my college project i am developing an app that uses **Angular** as front-end and an **ASP .NET WEB API** that is responsible for handling requests. I have implemented an authentication system that is already working. I can login and signup user accounts successfully, However, I have a controller for creating special users (admins, etc...) that needs the user to be logged in. For that, in my **Angular** app, I make the request and set a **Bearer token** in the header, through the use of an **Interceptor**:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpRequest, HttpHandler, HttpEvent, HttpInterceptor } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { AuthService } from '../services/auth.service';

@Injectable()
export class AuthenticationInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {

    constructor(private authSrv: AuthService) { }
    
    intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
        const token = this.authSrv.getToken();
        const cloned = req.clone({setHeaders: { Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`}})
        console.log(cloned);
        return next.handle(cloned);
    }
}
```

Here is the request that I make in AuthService:

```
registerAsAdmin(user: any): Observable<any> {
    return this.http.post<any>(`${this.apiUrl}/register-as-admin`, user).pipe(
      tap(user => this.handleUserRegistrationSuccess(user)),
      catchError(this.handleError<any>('Signup'))
    );
  }
```

This is what is shown on browser inspector when I make the request on my web-site:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FVC8q.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4w0BX.png)

When I try to make the request through my Angular App, I always get the 401 error code. But I have already tried with Postman and it works succesfully

Here is my controller:

```
        [Authorize]
        [HttpPost("register-as-admin")]
        public async Task<ActionResult<UserDTO>> RegisterOtherUser(CreatingUserDTO dto)
        {
            try
            {
                // Obter o valor do claim "user" do token
                var userEmail = User.FindFirst("user")?.Value;


                // Imprimir informações da solicitação no console
                Console.WriteLine("Bearer: " + HttpContext.Request.Headers["Authorization"]);
                Console.WriteLine($"Request Method: {HttpContext.Request.Method}");
                Console.WriteLine($"Request Path: {HttpContext.Request.Path}");
                Console.WriteLine($"Request Headers: {string.Join(", ", HttpContext.Request.Headers)}");
                // Adicione mais informações conforme necessário


                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(userEmail))
                {
                    // Obter utilizador
                    var loggedUser = await _userService.GetByEmailAsync(userEmail);

                    string[] allowedRoles = { "admin" };
                    // validate roles
                    if (RolesCheck.isAllowed(allowedRoles, loggedUser.Roles))
                    {
                        // Encrypt password
                        string hashPassword = BCrypt.Net.BCrypt.HashPassword(dto.Password);
                        dto.Password = hashPassword;

                        var user = await _userService.AddUser(dto);

                        return CreatedAtAction(nameof(GetById), new { id = user.Id }, user);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        return Forbid();
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    return Forbid();
                }

            }
            catch (BusinessRuleValidationException err)
            {
                return BadRequest(err.Message);
            }
        }
```

And then my Startup.cs:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;
using MongoExample.Models;
using MongoExample.Infrastructure.Users;
using MongoExample.Domain.Users;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer;
using Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens;
using System.Text;
using Users.Services;

namespace DDDSample1
{
    public class Startup
    {
        public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            Configuration = configuration;
        }

        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.Configure<MongoDBSettings>(Configuration.GetSection("MongoDB"));

            ConfigureMyServices(services);
            
            services.AddControllers().AddNewtonsoftJson();
        }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }
            else
            {
                // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
                app.UseHsts();
            }

            app.UseCors("CorsPolicy");
            app.UseHttpsRedirection();

            app.UseRouting();

            app.UseAuthentication();
            app.UseAuthorization();
            //app.UseTokenMiddleware();

            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapControllers();
            });
        }

        public void ConfigureMyServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {          
            services.AddMvc();
            services.AddTransient<IUserRepository,UserRepository>();
            services.AddTransient<UserService>();

            services.AddTransient<TokenService>();

            services.AddCors(options =>
            {
                options.AddPolicy("CorsPolicy",
                    builder => builder.AllowAnyOrigin()
                        .AllowAnyMethod()
                        .AllowAnyHeader());
            });


            services.AddControllers();

            var key = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(Configuration["SecretKey"]);

            services.AddAuthentication(x =>
            {
                x.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
                x.DefaultChallengeScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            })
            .AddJwtBearer(x =>
            {
                x.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;
                x.SaveToken = true;
                x.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
                {
                    ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
                    IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(key),
                    ValidateIssuer = false,
                    ValidateAudience = false
                };
            });
        }
    }
}
```

I have wasted a lot of hours on this and still haven't figured out what is causing the problem. One thing that I noticed is that the Bearer token doesn't appear when I do **Console.WriteLine("Bearer: " + HttpContext.Request.Headers["Authorization"])**, but when I use Postman it shows successfully. **Obs**.: Of course, in order to test this line of code I removed the [Authorize] from the controller.

Comment: sounds like a CORS issue.  (Whenever Postman works and browser doesn't that's what it usually is because Postman has no CORS rules.)  In particular, when sending credentials, you cannot set wildcard for origins.  (you can't use ".AllowAnyOrigin()")  This may work when you actually publish, since the request should be same-origin then.  While debugging you may have separate ports for localhost running angular vs backend which would be separate domains/origins.

Comment: Welcome to SO! I suggest that you do not post images as links; instead, just paste where  you want it to show up.